# MySQL Table Partitioning: Partitioning related tables

Tags: mysql, database

I want to use `PARTITION` in my MySQL database and I want to partition by date. However, I have 7 related tables and only one has a timestamp column. The other tables are related to that one table through an ID. I'm using software I didn't write so I can't really modify the code that `INSERT`s the records. Is there a way to relate partitions between multiple tables? e.g. if I drop the partition with date 2015-07-15, it will drop all corresponding records on every related table.

I've been thinking about using MySQL triggers but I don't think dropping a table is an operation that counts as a `DELETE` so my triggers won't be invoked.

Comment: no. there is no multi-table partitioning. the partition rules work on fields within the table, and only the fields within the table. nor is there a way to cascade drop tables.

Comment: If I LEFT JOIN the tables first then drop a partition, will the records on the other tables be dropped as well?

Comment: why can't you just use foreign keys? partitions only affect how the data is stored within the internal db files. they have nothing (directly) to do with how you query/insert/update/delete the data.

Comment: I'm working with upwards of tens of millions of rows. If I go through one of the 6 other tables without a timestamp column using foreign keys, it will still be very slow because I will be deleting tens of millions of rows in 6 tables (instead of 7).